# verify a numerical value using .submit jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input, numeric

I have the following where am I trying to verify firstly that the user has entered a value and second that the numeric value matches that of a random number from 1-8 generated through php.

HTML / PHP

```
<?php
    $num = rand(1,8);
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    var js_var = '.json_encode($num).';
    </script>';
    ?>
<p>The ball will start at position '<span class="number"></span>' and travel in a straight line.</p>
<p class="question">Where will the ball roll to?</p>
<form action="javascript:alert('You are correct');" id="form">
    <input type="text" id="field">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<p id="target"></p>
```

JS

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        // add in random start position
        $('.number').text(js_var);

        // grab submitted answer
        $('#form').submit(function(event){
            var answer = $('#field').val();


            if( $('#answer').val() != ' ') {
                if ( answer == js_var) {
                    $('#target').text("Correct!").show();
                    return;
                } 
                    $('#target').text("Incorrect, try again!"+js_var).show().fadeOut(1000);
                    event.preventDefault(); 

             } else {
                 alert('Please enter a value...!');
                 event.preventDefault(); 
             }
        })
    });
</script>
```

I can't seam to get it to validate at all....

Comment: I got rid of the php code to generate the random number and added the `$num` variable in as 6. I've added this at: http://jsfiddle.net/pv8Ce/11/ The verification for matching the number works but not the check for `null` (user not entering anything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
if( $('#answer').val() != ' ')
```

you can use

```
if( $('#answer').val().length > 0)
```